# Cannot get parent element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html structure created dynamically by foreach loop and tried to remove the whole  element by accessing it from  (ACTIVE HYPERLINK). I tried many different way, but cannot reach to it. As the whole block (of ACTIVE HYPERLINK) is repeated, I think it is meaningless to use class name of the hyperlink. I also tried to use a.active but not seem to work.

```
@foreach (var file in Model.FileAttachments)
{
    <li class="aaa">
        <div class="bbb">
            <div class="ccc">
                <div class="ddd">                   
                    <div class="eee">
                        <ul class="fff">
                            <li>
                                <a class="xxx" href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="@file.Id" data-toggle="confirmation" ></a> <!-- ACTIVE HYPERLINK -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
}

<script>

    $('.xxx').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation('show');
    });


    $('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation({
        //code omitted for brevity      
        onConfirm: function () { deleteRecord(); }, // Set event when click at confirm button
    });


    function deleteRecord() {
        var $ctrl = $('.xxx');

        $.ajax({
        //code omitted for brevity

        success: function (response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            if (response.success) {             
                ctrl.closest('.aaa').remove();
                //or                
                $("a.active").closest('.jFiler-item').remove();
            }
        });

    };

</script>
```

Here is some example of my tries:

```
$("a.active").closest('.aaa').remove();
$(".xxx").closest('.aaa').remove();
$(this).data('.aaa')remove();
$("a.active").parents('li').eq(2)remove();
$(".xxx").parents('li').eq(2)remove();
```

Any idea?

Comment: use `closest()` ... That one goes up the tree untill it hits the argument given.

Comment: @guest271314 What is the solution? Any suggestion pls?

Comment: @ClintEastwood Are you trying to remove the direct `<li>` parent of `<a>` element when `<a>` element is clicked? Does actual `html` used have `href` attribute set at `<a>` elements?

Comment: No element having `className` `"active"` appears at `html`? `var $ctrl = $('.xxx');` selects all `.xxx` elements, not only clicked `.xxx` element; `ctrl.closest('.aaa').remove();` would only remove first `.xxx` element.

Comment: I thought active like hover, but when  debugging by Firebug and break, there seems to be no active class (I inspected the clicked hyperlink).

Comment: `:active` is a `css` pseudo class, not a `className`

Comment: It does not add a class. `:active` is a state between *click --- release*. Doesn't need `href` to be set.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange _"Doesn't need href to be set."_ ? How can `a` element be `:active` where no `href` is present as attribute? What would be `:active`?

Comment: Yeah. Its a state of user activation. Does not depend on href. [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active) .. You can apply it on a div element too for that matter.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange You are correct http://plnkr.co/edit/lBdOuwO4bZ8vcXpyVPch?p=preview

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Workaround to save the state? https://jsfiddle.net/u3uhq9m1/1/

Comment: Can I get the active hyperlink (last clicked one) for this scenario? Any idea?

Comment: @ClintEastwood Yes, `javascript` at Answer should achieve this, as `this` is passed directly to `deleteRecord`. Is `$.fn.confirmation` defined at `javascript` at Question? Link to documentation? Have also composed a workaround.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966288/how-to-pass-css-active-pseudo-element-to-javascript/39966289#39966289

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED RESPONSE**

```
$('.xxx').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation({
        //code omitted for brevity      
        onConfirm: function () {
            deleteRecord($this); // send reference to delete method
        }
    });
    $('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation('show');
});

...

function deleteRecord($ctrl) {
...
```

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE**

If you want the block removed on click on the `<a>` element, you need to assign a handler to the `click` event:

```
$('.xxx').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.aaa').remove();
});
```

Comment: Normally I was using **$(this).closest()** but this time I have multiple javascript method and after click function I opened a confirmation dialog and then call AJAX in this method. For this reason I cannot use $(this) as it throw an error "not defined" or "null". So, I need to catch the clicked link and I cannot use also class name as there are multiple hyperlink. Any idea?

Comment: agreed, @ZoliSzabo's answer is correct, but we won't be able to see what issues you're having with the current context without an example.

Comment: @autoboxer If `<a>` element has `href` attribute the `document` would either be reloaded, or redirected to another resource at `click`? Where removing parent element would have no affect?

Comment: It works only the first time because it sends the same id (the first clicked's). Should we need to define some parameter as global? I think we are so close to the solution. Thanks...

Comment: I made some assumptions on how the confirmation plugin works. Probably that is the cause of it. Which plugin is that?

Comment: A simple hack would indeed be to use some global variable to store the current $this and use that global variable in the `deleteRecord` method instead of the method argument. Let me know if you need help with this version and I will update my answer.

Comment: @ZoliSzabo I use bootstrap confirmation, but it works properly and I have already used in my project. On the other hand, when click Delete button, the confirmation dialog open as much as loop(s). So, I think it is good idea to use a global variables for $this (to catch the first clicked element) and id (the get the clicked element's id). Could you please modify your answer. During this I will also make some tries. Thanks a lot...

Comment: @ZoliSzabo Many thanks for your help. I solved the problem with the help of you. Voted+

Answer (score 2):

Use event delagation, `event.preventDefault()` at `click` of `<a>` element to prevent default action of current document reloading or redirection to another resource; pass current `event.target` : `this` to `deleteRecord()`

```
$(document).on("click", ".xxx", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var curr = $(this);
    curr.confirmation('show')
    .confirmation({
      // pass `curr` to `deleteRecord()`
      onConfirm: function () { deleteRecord(curr); }
    })
});


function deleteRecord(el) {

    $.ajax({
    //code omitted for brevity

    success: function (response, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        if (response.success) {             
            el.closest('.aaa').remove();
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: I tried this answer at first, but the code cannot hit deleteRecord method ans seems to hit onclick event as  foreach loops. It seems to be so cleaner but I think there is a little mistake. Could you ha  a look at please and revise if needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Is `javascript` at Answer wrapped within `$(document).ready()` handler? Is `$.fn.confirmation` defined?

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I solved the problem with the help of you. Voted+

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final answer that is working like a charm with the help of **@ZoliSzabo** and **guest271314**. Many thanks for your help and suggestions...

```
@foreach (var file in Model.FileAttachments)
{
    <li class="aaa">
        <div class="bbb">
            <div class="ccc">
                <div class="ddd">                   
                    <div class="eee">
                        <ul class="fff">
                            <li>
                                <a class="xxx" href="javascript:void(0);" 
    data-id="@file.Id" data-toggle="confirmation" ></a> <!-- ACTIVE HYPERLINK -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
}



<script>

    var $ctrl = null; //define variables globally 
    var id = 0; //define variables globally 

    $('.icon-jfi-trash').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $ctrl = $(this);
        id = $(this).data('id');
        $(this).find('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation('show');
    });


    $('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation({
        //code omitted for brevity
        onConfirm: function () { deleteRecord(); }
    });




    function deleteRecord() {
        var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteRecord", "Controller")',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token , id: id },

            success: function (response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $ctrl.closest('.jFiler-item').remove();
                }
            }
        });
    }

<script>
```